# I'm having trouble evaluating a definite integral using the second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The integral is from 1 to 4, with $ \frac{x-7}{\sqrt{x}} dx$  in the integrand. I tried separating the fraction into $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{7}{\sqrt{x}}$  and integrating from there, and I got -9$\frac{1}{3}$. I checked my work on a calculator, and got the same answer, but it's still wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

we can write $$x^{1/2}-7x^{-1/2}$$ and the primitive function is given by
$$\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}-2\cdot 7x^{1/2}$$ then we get
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot 4^{3/2}-14\cdot 4^{1/2}-\left(\frac{2}{3}-14\right)$$